# Replacing a vertical sublist in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, matrix, replace

This question is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898023/replacing-a-sublist-with-another-sublist-in-python) question.

I'm representing a two-dimensional array using list of lists, `L`, say:

```
[ [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4] ]
```

For a given sub-list, say `[9, 99]`, I want to replace a specific sub-list in the "2-D" list by this `sublist` using something intuitive like:

```
L[1][0:2] = sublist

# which updates `L` to:

[ [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 9, 99, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4] ] # not in this format, but written like this for clarity
```

This works for horizontal replacements, but not for vertical replacements since, as we can't slice to separate lists like this: `L[0:2][0]`. If I **had** to use this slicing system, I could [transpose `L`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) ([Transpose list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists)), then use this slicing method, then transpose it back. But that's not efficient, even for the sake of simplicity.

**What would be an efficient way to replicate** `L[0:2][0]` **and get this output?**

```
[ [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 9, 3, 4],
  [1, 99, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4] ]
```

*Note:* Assume `len(sublist) <= len(L)`, for vertical replacements (which is the focus of this question).

Comment: Use Numpy arrays.

Comment: @Kasramvd  I want a solution without Numpy if possible. All other standard functions are fine

Comment: How do you want to receive the parameters? Is sublist and index (in this case column) ok?

Comment: L[0:2][0]=L[0][0]+L[1][0], so treat vertical replacements as loop for horizontal replacements

Comment: @Walucas Yes. I wanted a one-liner assignment like that of the example I gave for horizontal sub-list replacement, but anything is better if it's more performant.

Comment: @Sphinx I've tried that and, of course, it works. I wanted a more concise way to do it like that of the example I gave to horizontal sub-list replacement.

Comment: I don't think exists more efficient way. Because the data is saved in memory by horizontal not vertical. Anyway, the memory still can't support horizontal and vertical at the same time until now.

Comment: u don't want to transpose at all? even without numpy, like list(zip(*l))

Comment: @Walucas `list(zip(*l))` is fine

Comment: @Walucas until now, we come out two solutions: 'transpose' or 'loop for horizontal replacement', which way is more efficient?

Comment: Is `replaceVert(a,['ä','ü'],2,2)` a one liner? That would be the looped variant. I leave the zipped (==transpose/slice/transpose) version in, for ppl that find this question later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Looping approach:**

```
def replaceVert(al : list, repl:list, oIdx:int, iIdx:int):
    for pos in range(len(repl)):
        al[oIdx+pos][iIdx] =  repl[pos]

a = [ [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 6, 7, 8],
      [9, 10, 11, 12],
      [13, 14, 15, 16] ]

print(a)   # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

replaceVert(a,['ä','ü'],2,2)  # this is a one liner ;)

print(a)   # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 'ä', 12], [13, 14, 'ü', 16]]
```

---

**Transpose/slice/transpose approach:**

I overread the mentioning of "no transposing". This is using *transpose, change, transpose* method with slicing **which is not wanted by the Q**. It *is* a answer for the title of this question, so I decided to leave it in for future people search SO and stumble over this Q:

```
a = [ [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 6, 7, 8],
      [9, 10, 11, 12],
      [13, 14, 15, 16] ] 

b = list(map(list,zip(*a)))  # will make [ [1,5,9,13], ... ,[4,8,12,16]]
b[1][0:2]=['a','b']          # replaces what you want here (using a and b for clarity)
c = list(map(list,zip(*b)))  # inverts b back to a's form

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]     # a
[[1, 5, 9, 13], ['a', 'b', 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15], [4, 8, 12, 16]] # b replaced 
[[1, 'a', 3, 4], [5, 'b', 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]] # c
```

---

**Timing 4x4 list, 2 replaces**:

```
setuptxt = """
def replaceVert(al : list, repl:list, oIdx:int, iIdx:int):
    for pos in range(len(repl)):
        al[oIdx+pos][iIdx] =  repl[pos]

a = [ [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 6, 7, 8],
      [9, 10, 11, 12],
      [13, 14, 15, 16] ]
"""
zipp = """b = list(map(list,zip(*a)))  
b[1][0:2]=['a','b']           
c = list(map(list,zip(*b)))
"""

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("replaceVert(a,['ä','ü'],2,2)",setup = setuptxt))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=zipp, setup=setuptxt))
```

Output:

```
looping: 12.450226907037592
zipping: 7.50479947070815
```

The method wit ZIPPing (transpose/slice/transpose) needs roughly 60% of the time for 4x4 lists.

---

**Bigger list 1000x1000 and ~70 elements replaced:**

```
setuptxt = """
def replaceVert(al : list, repl:list, oIdx:int, iIdx:int):
    for pos in range(len(repl)):
        al[oIdx+pos][iIdx] =  repl[pos]

a = [ [kk for kk in range(1+pp,1000+pp)] for pp in range(1,1000)] 
repl = [chr(mm) for mm in range(32,100)]
"""

import timeit


print(timeit.timeit("replaceVert(a,repl,20,5)",number=500, setup = setuptxt))

zipp = """b = list(map(list,zip(*a)))  
b[20][5:5+len(repl)]=repl           
c = list(map(list,zip(*b)))
"""

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=zipp, setup=setuptxt,number=500))
```

Output:

```
looping: 0.07702917579216137
zipping: 69.4807168493871
```

Looping wins. Thanks @Sphinx for his comment

Comment: @Sphinx thanks for pointing it out. I leave the answer in, because someone finding this questions won't know from the questions title that this solution in this situation is off-limits.

Comment: Can you please provide `timeit` results for both the approaches? It seems there may not be a performant "pythonic" way to solve this question, which was my intention. Numpy is clearly a better solution, but I can't use it on online judges/competitions, hence this question.

Comment: I think Numpy uses first approaches=[looped-one-liner apporoach] for vertical replacements. If the matrix is very huge, I don't think transpose can be completed quickly.

Comment: @Sphinx now I know why np prefers looping :o)