# Replace beginning of a list with values from another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

For the lists A and B below:

```
A=[8, 4, 5]

B=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I would like to combine them to give 'C':

```
C=[8,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Code I have tried:

```
C = [B(x) for x in A else 0 for x in B]
```

But I recieve a syntax error.

Can someone help with the correct syntax to achieve the 'Desired Output'. Thankyou.

Comment: What should happen if the values in `B` are not zeros? Do you simply replace them or add them?

Comment: C = A + B[len(A):]

Comment: If the values in B are not zeros then just replace them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a sublist with another sublist in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898023/replacing-a-sublist-with-another-sublist-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
C = A + B[len(A):]
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean with combine. If you want to add the lists elementwise I would recommend using numpy:

import numpy as np

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
C = [*A, *B]
```